# Cannot use await on exported function?

Tags: reactjs, axios, es6-promise, next.js

I have an APIService wrapper around Axios, and I return it and was using .then() to handle the promise, but now I want to use async/await; I wonder why my function no longer works in this new scenario; as I only add a couple of configurations to the Axios instance before returning it.

The logic of moving to async/await is because that seems to be the best-practice manner of using nextjs and getInitialProps.

My APIService.js;

```
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from './constants';

const config = {
  baseURL: API_URL,
};

const APIService = axios.create(config);

APIService.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  const token = 'blah;
  request.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
  return request;
});

APIService.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // do something
      return true;
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default APIService;
```

I want the above function to work when called like this;

```
import APIService from '../../utils/APIService';

Page.getInitialProps = async function({ res, query }) {

  const req = await APIService.get('/endpoint', {});

  const { data } = req;

  return {
    data
  };
};
```

How should I refactor my APIService to work in the above scenario, and why is the refactor needed as I don't manipulate how the Axios function works...

Comment: you can't use on globe scope unless encapsulated with `async` function

Comment: You can only call `await` when inside an `async` function.  You will have to put your call to `const req = await APIService.get('/endpoint', {});` inside an `async` function.  For now, that can't be at the top level of a module.  It has to be inside a function.

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair - Just to be entirely accurate, the top level of a module scope is not global scope.  It's module scope.  The issue is that (until we get top level `await` in modules) you have to be inside an `async` function to use `await` and the top level of module scope is not inside an `async` function.

Comment: Could someone use my code as example of how I need to rewrite it please? It is called from inside an async function.. I will update my code.

Answer (score 0):

`await` cannot be used on the top-level, it must be inside an async function. There is a common practice to solve this however, it is not recommended:

```js
(async function() {
  const response = await APIService.get('/endpoint', {});
  ...
}());

// or

(async function() {
  const response = await APIService.get('/endpoint', {});
  ...
}()).then(...);
```

There is a proposal to allow async imports on top level but it is still in stage 3.
You can read more on this topic in [this article](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await)

Comment: I just clarified how I am calling it in an async function. I just dont understand why await axios works and await APIService doesnt... so the issue must be my APIService.js

Comment: @dhj I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ikarasz/2befe3a816508327cb936076f880fa0d), it works like a charm on my localhost. What I've found:
- It works if I get the response from the server. (`/` endpoint)
- The promise rejects, so I get the default error page if the status code is other than 2XX or 401. (`/not-found` endpoint)
- I get a js error in case of 401 since we resolve with true which has no data key. (`/unauthorized` endpoint)

So maybe the return true breaks your code, or I need more information about the problem.
How do you mean 'it no longer works'?

Comment: You helped me debug it, it was a path error; but now the initial confusion makes sense - I did not manipulate the original APIService so it works fine with await or then - all now works perfectly. So thank you @ikarasz

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the API_URL I had defined, the issue did not bubble up the stack, it was as simple as a double // in the path.

Answer (score -1):

Async and Await are extensions of promises.They are actually built on top of promises.Await cannot be used outside an Async function.Remember these rules for asunc and await.

1. You Must Use the await keyword only in closure that is declared with the async keyword.
2. Inside of an async closure, if another async function is called with the await keyword, the next line will not run until that line’s promise has resolved.

   async function myFunc() {
     return 10;
   }

   myFunc().then(alert); //OUTPUT: 10

Async tells you that a promise will be returned, if promise is not returned javascript automatically puts it in the resolved part. Running myFunc().then() works because myFunc is returning a promise.If Async and await is nor working for you try writing a custom promise and see if it works.You can goto this link [Promise - JavaScript](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)